# Can not reversed sort of ArrayList in java

Tags: java, sorting, reverse

Today I would like to sort my List of Movie by rating. I use sort method like below and it works fine till I would like to make a reversed order.

```
List<Movie> result = movieRepository.findAll();
result.sort(Comparator.comparing(m->m.getRating()));
```

That works perfect however when I try to do something like that:

```
 List<Movie> result = movieRepository.findAll();
 result.sort(Comparator.comparing(m->m.getRating()).reversed());
```

It shows me that:`Cannot resolve method getRating()`. So he can resolve it until I try to make it reversed order? What is going on here?

Comment: `result.sort(Comparator.comparing((Movie m) -> m.getRating()).reversed());`

Comment: The most preferred option: `result.sort(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getRating).reversed());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there's some bug in compiler that they somehow can't guess the correct type when chaining `Comparator`.

In your case you can workaround by using method reference:

```
List<Movie> result = movieRepository.findAll();
result.sort(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getRating).reversed());
```